# mysql select rows as columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an sql table looking like this

```
---------------------------------
| id | di  | field  |  content  |
---------------------------------
| 1  | kh  |  dvh   | lorem ips |
---------------------------------
| 2  | kh  |  kkf   | hor ameti |
---------------------------------
| 3  | db  |  hgd   | usyytutt  |
---------------------------------
```

What I would like is a way to select from sql and return the variables where `field` becomes the column name; like so:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE `di` = "kh"'); // And some more fancy code
$sql = execute();
$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $row['dvh'];

// outputs 'lorem ips'
```

Currently I am using php to convert the returned array by using:

`$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

and then running them through a foreach loop:

```
$data = array();

foreach ($result as $k => $val) {
    $data[$val['field']] = $data['content'];
}
```

I really want SQL to do this for me.

Comment: This is called a dynamic pivot.  Google "MySQL dynamic pivot".

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted Why? :-(

Comment: @Strawberry I am listing some products in a table but instead of having a column for each possible input field or information, I am using this method to store multiple values for an id. This also ensures that I don't end up with a lot of empty fields, when only a few products require a specific information that none of the others require.

Comment: @DaveSalomon I would say that your reference actually looks like what I need, but I didn't know how to search my way into that answer.. i will take a look at it thanks..

Comment: @GordonLinoff It doesn't seem like MySQL has a pivot function.. I should go for the GROUP_CONCAT() function

Comment: Just stick with post-processing the result in PHP. It's way more scalable AND flexible!